# C - Counting minutes from a specific date

Tags: c, pointers, time, count, integer

I need to calculate how many minutes have passed since a certain date (1600), but I do not always get the results I would expect.The variable minutes is equal to zero and is of type long long int.For example, for the date 2:18 10/14/1900, I will present 158093418 instead of 158197098, etc .

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int leapYear (int y) {
    if ( y % 4 == 0 && ( y % 100 != 0 || y % 400 == 0 ))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void zjistiDny (int y, int m, int d, int h, int i, long long int *minutes)
{
    int mesic [13] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    long long int days = 0;
    
    for ( int i = 1600; i < y; i++ )
    {
        days += 365;
        if (leapYear(y)){
            days += 1;
        }

    }
    
    for ( int i = 1; i <m; i++)
    {
        if (i != 2)
        {
            days += mesic[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if (leapYear(y))
            {
                days += 1;
            }
            days += mesic[i];
        } 
    
            
    }

    days += d;
    *minutes += days*1440;
    *minutes += h*60;
    *minutes += i;
        
}

int main () 
{
    long long int minutes1 = 0, minutes2 = 0, minutes = 0;
    int y1 = 1900, m1= 10, d1 = 14, h1 = 2, i1 = 18;
    int y2 = 1950, m2= 11, d2 = 27, h2 = 6, i2 = 53;
    
    zjistiDny(y1,m1,d1,h1,i1,&minutes1);
    zjistiDny(y2,m2,d2,h2,i2,&minutes2);
    
    printf("minuty1: %lld\n", minutes1);
    printf("minuty1: %lld\n", minutes2);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You have a use case which you have the expectation value and the actual value, which differ. So you have a good way to start *debugging*. Step through the program, look at intermediate results and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `for ( int i = 1; i <m; i++)` is what you want, rather than  `for ( int i = 0; i <m; i++)` ?  (indexing is zero base in `C`.)

Comment: @ryyker the op has months array (`mesic`) starting with value `0`. I guess they should realize the proper indexing, rather than patching it...

Comment: yes, because the first element of the array is zero

Comment: @Aaron7 So the point that it should not be zero. What is the meaning of zero? There is none. You just put it there because you are indexing it starting with `1`. But the indexing should start with zero.

Comment: I wanted it to be more intuitive January = 1, February = 2, etc..

Comment: The discrepancy in minutes is an exact number of days (72) if that helps point you.

Comment: @Aaron7 If you are into C, then you need to retrain your intuition :) After a while 0-based indexing will make much more sense to you than 1-based.

Comment: The first `if (leapYear(y))` should be `if (leapYear(i))` because you are counting the days in each *intervening* year in a loop.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice it, but I have a small mistake somewhere else because now it tells me 158198538.I will edit the post

Comment: Please don't update the question with the answer!

Comment: That is `1440` difference, so **one day**. Are you counting the end day?

Comment: I wanted to fix it, because there's still another mistake.

Comment: In that case, add to the question, but please don't change it.

Comment: Aside: did you know that 11 days were removed from the calendar in September 1752, when it was changed from the Julian calendar to the Gregorian calendar? See [Give Us Our Eleven Days](https://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofBritain/Give-us-our-eleven-days/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems in OP's original post:

**Since**

Count minutes *since* Jan 1, 1600 0:00. The 1st day of the month is zero days since the month's beginning, not 1.

```
// days += d;
days += d - 1;
```

**Call with the year, not month index**

```
// if (leapYear(i)){
if (leapYear(y)){
```

---

Recommend to zero `minutes` in `zjistiDny()` and return the minutes

```
long long zjistiDny (int y, int m, int d, int h, int i) {
  long long minutes = 0;
  ...
  minutes += days*1440;
  minutes += h*60;
  minutes += i;
  return minutes;
}
```

---

Alternative code using `<time.h>` and assuming `time_t` is seconds since 1970/1/1 0:00:00, and `mktime()` good for years [2000-2399].  Assume [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)

```
#include <time.h>
#define DAYSPER400YEARS (400L * 365 + 100 - 3)
#define MINSPER400YEARS (DAYSPER400YEARS * 24LL * 60)

long long minutes(int year, int mon, int day, int hour, int min) {
  int year400since2000 = year/400 - 5;
  year = year%400 + 2000;
  struct tm tm = {0};
  tm.tm_year = year - 1900;
  tm.tm_mon = mon - 1;
  tm.tm_mday = day;
  tm.tm_mday = day;
  tm.tm_hour = hour;
  tm.tm_min = min;
  time_t t = mktime(&tm);
  assert(t != -1);
  t /= 60;
  t += year400since2000 * MINSPER400YEARS;
  return t;
}
```